# Cannot push JSON elements to array inside for loop called from useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have an array `candleRealTimeDataQueue` which is not getting updated properly. Please find the code below:

```
    let candleCurrentJSONDataWS = null;
    var candleRealTimeDataQueue = [];
    let tempDateTime = null;
    let candleJsonData = {};


    useEffect(() => {
        getDataFromAPI();
    }, []);

    ...

    const getDataFromAPI = async () => {
        let apiDataFetch = await fetch('https:/api/endpoint');

        let response = await apiDataFetch.json();    // data from api obtained correctly
                                                     // total 4 values
        
        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

            tempDateTime = new Date(parseInt(response[i][0]));
            candleJsonData['time'] = tempDateTime.toString();
             
            candleJsonData['open'] = parseFloat(response[i][1]);
            candleJsonData['high'] = parseFloat(response[i][2]);
            candleJsonData['low'] = parseFloat(response[i][3]);
            candleJsonData['close'] = parseFloat(response[i][4]);

            console.log(candleJsonData); // this correctly prints different 
                                         // data for each different i

            candleRealTimeDataQueue.push(candleJsonData);
            console.log(candleRealTimeDataQueue);   // PROBLEM is here: At the end
                                                    // candleRealTimeDataQueue array all
                                                    // have SAME elements. Its wrong. All
                                                    // 4 elements are of i = 3
        }
    }
```

Problem is at the end `candleRealTimeDataQueue` has 4 elements and all the elements are same. This should not happen because I am pushing **DIFFERENT** `candleJsonData` elements in the `candleRealTimeDataQueue` array in the for loop. Please help.

Comment: What is `.json()` in `apiDataFetch.json()`

Comment: problem is here  `for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)` change it to `  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++)`

Comment: @brk It converts the response to json format.

Comment: @meisam Tried that but did not work.

Comment: Also change this `candleRealTimeDataQueue.push(candleJsonData);` to `candleRealTimeDataQueue.push({...candleJsonData});`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem here is that you are reusing the `candleJsonData` object. When you run `candleRealTimeDataQueue.push(candleJsonData)`, you are pushing the reference to `candleJsonData` into `candleRealTimeDataQueue`. So at the end of the loop, you have four references to the same object inside `candleRealTimeDataQueue`. And since you are modifying the same `candleJsonData` object over and over again, you'll just see four identical json data inside the queue when you log it and all four elements will be of `i = 3`.

Instead, you should be creating new `candleJsonData` objects inside your loop. So something like

```
        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

            tempDateTime = new Date(parseInt(response[i][0]));
            let candleJsonData = {}
            candleJsonData['time'] = tempDateTime.toString();
             
            candleJsonData['open'] = parseFloat(response[i][1]);
            candleJsonData['high'] = parseFloat(response[i][2]);
            candleJsonData['low'] = parseFloat(response[i][3]);
            candleJsonData['close'] = parseFloat(response[i][4]);
            candleRealTimeDataQueue.push(candleJsonData);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

it is because of the `candleJsonData` variable which is declared outside, so latest value is overriding previous value. In face there is no need of that variable and it can directly push in the array.

```
 var candleRealTimeDataQueue = [];

  React.useEffect(() => {
    getDataFromAPI().then((data) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        candleRealTimeDataQueue.push({
          time: new Date(parseInt(data[i][0])).toString(),
          open: parseFloat(data[i][1]),
          low: parseFloat(data[i][3]),
          close: parseFloat(data[i][4]),
        });
      }
    });
    return () => {
      // do clean up here
    };
  }, []);

  const getDataFromAPI = () => {
    return fetch('https:/api/endpoint');
  };
```